# How to make Fetch API work without enabling CORS in the browser

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I have been trying to get this code to work in various versions:
(the URL points to the NASA APOD API)

```
  try {
    const rsp = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
      },
    })
    if (rsp.ok) {
      console.log(`>>> no problem with call to fetch api:`)
      const data = await rsp.json()
      return data
    }
    console.log(`!!! some other problem occurred with call to fetch api:`, rsp)

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`!!! problem with call to fetch api:`, err)
  }
```

I have been getting this error:
[image]

when I run the code in Chrome. However, when I run the same code in FireFox, I get the expected data returned from the API.

When I install an extension in Chrome to enable CORS, I get the expected data returned from the API.

[image]

When I run the code with the fetch header - 'mode': 'no-cors', I get the following response in Chrome:

[image]

which I can understand to a point because the API is on a different domain (i.e. from NASA). FireFox gives a similar response.

So, I have reached the point where I can make the code in Chrome by switching on CORS in the browser (by means of browser extension). This is clearly not satisfactory.

I would appreciate any suggestions on resolving this problem in Chrome that does involve using a browser-level switching on of CORS.

Latest Attempt:

[image]

this is the NextJS api route.

[image]

this is the function using axios to call the API route

[image]

this is error from axios.

It looks like the proxy is not working, the `responseUrl` looks like it is coming from local host not the target API address.

Any ideas please?

Comment: You don't. You'll need to proxy it via an API you can add the right headers to.

Comment: Additionally: if I run the url directly in Chrome (from the address bar), the api does return the data correctly. ???

Comment: ...yes? It's not a cross-origin request when you make it from the same origin.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - please tell me what headers would alleviate this problem.

Comment: This is thoroughly explained in e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I have read this article many times and tried many versions of my code with different header combinations - to no avail. Can you explain to me why if I take a url from my code (that triggers the cors error in my code) and enter it directly into Chrome (from the address bar) no cors error occurs?

Comment: Because that's **not a cross-origin request**. And the _client_ can't set these headers, if it could then CORS protection would be totally pointless.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I understand now that the "Access-Control- ..." headers can only be issued from the server side. Some of the posts were not clear which side of the equation the suggestions are directed. "not a cross-origin request" - so, requests sent from the Chrome address bar are not subject to the restrictions of the CORS policy? Would elaborate a bit more on this area (this seems odd given that it is possible to disable CORS using a Chrome browser extension). Also, please look at my post below regarding my latest failed code attempt. Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

The API doesn't belong to you, technically, it's no way to call that API from your frontend to that API, don't try to config your frontend or browser because it doesn't help.

You can try:

- Check the document from that API to allow calling from your specific origin domain.
- Create your own proxy server and then instead of calling from your frontend --> That API, you can call "Your frontend --> Your Proxy --> The API" (Of cause, you still have to config your proxy allow your frontend if they don't running on a same domain)

Comment: @QuangHoa - RE "no way to call that API from your frontend" - my origin question stated that my code runs without any CORS error in FireFox. The problem occurs in Chrome. Additionally, I just tried my code in Edge - no CORS errors

Comment: I have tried various ways to access the api using fetch via a proxy - no avail. The situation is further complicated because the application is implemented with NextJS. Do you have any idea how to approach setting up a proxy in this environment?

Comment: I an now to do this proxy via a NextJS api route using http-proxy-middleware

Comment: Very well, I believe it works. I'm not a fan of NextJs but I see they have the example here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes-cors/pages/api/cors.js

Comment: And also the document https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options

Comment: please look at the code for my NextJs version of the code - with the error

Comment: @Quang- github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options, this article appears to be for configuring the server-side of an api - from a very quick perusal,  is that right? Now - github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes-cors/… - this article seems to be presenting yet another approach to this problem - I will try to implement it now. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Quang- github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options, I implemented this code and I get the CORS error (... blocked by CORS policy). No help at all... It does not seem to make any attempt at using a proxy.

Comment: @Quang - both of those articles are to do with server side code. I am trying to access an external api (NASA Apod).

Comment: When I access the api from the Chrome address bar: https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=jDpuF0V85x4F99c50zfs182iKJgpnA7gbUKCKsgh&date=2022-06-01... the data comes back from the server without any error. The response from the server is

Comment: When I access the api from the Chrome address bar: https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=<my-nasa-api-key>&date=2022-06-01... the data comes back from the server without any error. The response from the server shows "Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin" - which seems to mean, block cors requests. This does not make sense to me because when I access my site through FireFox and Edge there is no cors error. ???

Comment: @Tonio Can you try this one, I have check it and as you said, no CORS error https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-tree-5m813v?file=/index.html

Comment: I answered your question based on the CORS error. But it seem the Nasa API allows all frontend already (they have already confined their API)

Comment: @Quang - in what browser are you running the code you suggested. I ask because I have similar code that generates the cors policy error in Chrome, but in FireFox and Edge the same code runs without the cors policy error (the data comes back as expected)